# Verilog bit shift by constant, how is it implemented?

Tags: verilog

I have a line of code like

```
parameter [8:0] param1=8'd05, param2 = 8'd20;
A <= cond ? (1 << param1) : (1 << param2);
```

Will the compiler recognize `1 << param` is a constant and replace that expression with a constant or will it try to implement some sort of bit shifter?

Comment: compiler will recognize it as a constant .

Comment: Do you mean compiler or synthesis tool? After sysnthesis look at the gates for the module and you should be able to see only two options available for shifting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameters are evaluated at compile time and must be constants.

From IEEE Std 1364-2001:

> 3.11 Parameters Verilog HDL parameters do not belong to either the variable or the net group. **Parameters are not variables, they are
>   constants.**

So it is really up to the Synthesis tool how it will decide to implement a shift by that *constant*, but any reasonable implementation will simply select the correct wires out of the vector.

In addition, since your examples are constants shifted by a constant, the whole expression reduces to a constant and the code will be equivalent to:

```
A <= cond ? 32'h20 : 32'h100000;
```